# Create a new list under conditions from an existing one

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an external file (data.out) which I read it with Mathematica using

```
data = ReadList["data.out", Number, RecordLists -> True];
```

This file contains three columns `(x,y,f)` of thousands of data. Here is a small sample of it:

```
0.30000000        0.00000000      0.1679035061279048E+02
2.30000000        0.50000000      0.1195447110986367E+01
0.10000000        0.00000000      0.2179035061279048E+02
5.80000000        2.50000000      0.7195447110986367E+01
3.00000000        0.00000000      0.4679035061279048E+02
7.90000000        7.50000000      0.1195447110986367E+01
4.70000000        2.00000000      0.8679035061279048E+01
1.20000000        4.50000000      0.2195447110986367E+01
```

Now I want to use Mathematica in order to manipulate the `data` list creating a new one `dataMod` which will have this structure `(x,y,f,f1)`. Obviously, there is a new element `(f1)` in the `dataMod` list. Well, if $0\leq f < 5$, $f1$ should be a random number in the interval $10^{-4}< f1 \leq \sqrt2$, if $5\leq f < 7$, $f1$ should be a random number in the interval $10^{-7}\leq f1 \leq 10^{-4}$ and if $f \geq 7$ then $f1$ should be a random number in the interval $10^{-12} < f1 < 10^{-7}$.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I can only second @Anon´s comment: please show what you already tried and format any data so as to be useful for further use.

Comment: @YvesKlett Thanks for the reminder. I 'll take it into consideration in future questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple, for example:

```
f1[x_] := Which[
  0 <= x < 5, RandomReal[{10^(-4), Sqrt[2]}],
  5 <= x < 7, RandomReal[{ 10^(-7), 10^(-4)}],
  x >= 7, RandomReal[{10^(-12), 10^(-7)}]
  ]
dataMod = {##, f1[#3]} & @@@ data (* Kuba's version *)
```

Or in the final step

```
dataMod = {Sequence @@ #, f1[#[[3]]]} & /@ data (* Old version *)
```

It's a good idea to include what you've tried to do, so it shows you've made some effort to solve the problem yourself. Also when you want to include data you should include it as a list, in this case it's irrelevant that it was a file of that format to begin with.

Comment: hm, 52 seconds :)

Comment: @PinguinDirk Yup XD

Comment: deleted mine, same idea, next time it'll be mine :)

Comment: @PinguinDirk Ah ok, that was gracious. I didn't expect that, I will remember it for the next time :)

Comment: no need to remember, I'll just be faster :)

Comment: Instead of `Sequence` you can `{##, f1[#3]} & @@@ data` :)

Comment: @Kuba That looks a lot better, I will update my answer with that ty.